# Drupal 6 hook:  "field in a node-type has been added, modified or deleted"?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, cck

I see that hook_node_type() allows me to intercept and modify newly-created or newly-modified *node-types*.  But apparently, hook_node_type() is *not* triggered when the node's *field-definitions* are created or modified.

For example, when I create a node-type "my_bio", hook_node_type() gets triggered.  But if I then add a field "my_photo" to the "my_bio" node-type, then hook_node_type() is not triggered.

In Drupal 6, is there a way to write a hook that effectively extends hook_node_type(), so that the hook gets called when fields in a node-type are added or changed?

Alternatively, is there a hook that gets called when any field-definition is added or changed?

More specifically, this is what I am trying to accomplish:
I have two custom formatters which are "mates":  formatter_1 and formatter_2.  When some field in a nodetype is added or modified, I check whether the field's formatter is formatter_1.  If so, I then check whether the nodetype contains a "mate" for this field, i.e. a second field whose formatter is formatter_2.  If not, I add a field-mate to this nodetype.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

To address the update to your question...

CCK has a hook that gets fired whenever an instance of a field is attached to a node type, or an instance that is already attached to a node type is updated. It's called `hook_content_fieldapi()`; documentation seems to be pretty sketchy but it's mentioned in the [`content.crud.inc` file](http://api.drupalecommerce.org/api/cck/cck--includes--content.crud.inc/6.x/source) as having the following operations:

1. create instance
2. read instance
3. update instance
4. delete instance

The hook implementation would look something like:

```
function mymodule_content_fieldapi($op, $field) {
  if ($op == 'create instance') {
    if ($field->foo == 'bar') {
      // Do something
    }
  }
}
```

As 'instances' essentially define the relationship between a node type and a field, this should be a good place to start what you're trying to do. I'd recommend dumping out the values of `$field` in the hook to see what variables you've got to work with.

Comment: Thank you very much for this reference.  I now see that hook_field() is not what I need.  Apparently, hook_field() is called when nodes are submitted ("Content passes variables from the hook_nodeapi call to the hook_field"), as opposed to being called when a field-definition is submitted.  Thank you for helping me clarify my thoughts.  I will now modify the question ...

Comment: @user606696: I've updated the answer to reflect your new question, hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you so much.  I will give this a try and report back.